# Default parameter values

Tags: lists, itemize, parameters

What are the default values for the [itemize environment](http://latex.computersci.org/Reference/ListEnvironments#toc3) (`\itemsep`, `\labelsep`, `\labelwidth`, etc.)?

The below is an example of what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
 \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\the\itemsep`, `the\labelsep` etc or use `showthe\itemsep` etc.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This depends on the font size selected for the document class or within the text and whether you're in `\twocolumn` or not (at least, for the default document classes). For the exact lengths, you need to view [`size10.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size10.clo), [`size11.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size11.clo), [`size12.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size12.clo) in conjunction with the document class you're using. The following minimal example lists these totals for the various levels:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb|\itemsep:| \the\itemsep
  \item \verb|\labelsep:| \the\labelsep
  \item \verb|\labelwidth:| \the\labelwidth
  \item \verb|\parsep:| \the\parsep
  \item \verb|\topsep:| \the\topsep
  \item \verb|\partopsep:| \the\partopsep
  \item \verb|\leftmargin:| \the\leftmargin
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \verb|\itemsep:| \the\itemsep
    \item \verb|\labelsep:| \the\labelsep
    \item \verb|\labelwidth:| \the\labelwidth
    \item \verb|\parsep:| \the\parsep
    \item \verb|\topsep:| \the\topsep
    \item \verb|\partopsep:| \the\partopsep
    \item \verb|\leftmargin:| \the\leftmargin
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \verb|\itemsep:| \the\itemsep
      \item \verb|\labelsep:| \the\labelsep
      \item \verb|\labelwidth:| \the\labelwidth
      \item \verb|\parsep:| \the\parsep
      \item \verb|\topsep:| \the\topsep
      \item \verb|\partopsep:| \the\partopsep
      \item \verb|\leftmargin:| \the\leftmargin
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \verb|\itemsep:| \the\itemsep
        \item \verb|\labelsep:| \the\labelsep
        \item \verb|\labelwidth:| \the\labelwidth
        \item \verb|\parsep:| \the\parsep
        \item \verb|\topsep:| \the\topsep
        \item \verb|\partopsep:| \the\partopsep
        \item \verb|\leftmargin:| \the\leftmargin
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Some font-dependent settings include `\labelsep`, `\labelwidth` and `\leftmargin`. These are set at root level (in non-`\twocolumn` mode) to be

- `\labelsep`: `.5em`;
- `\leftmargin`: `2.5em`;
- `\labelwidth`: `\leftmargin` - `\labelsep` = `2.5em` - `.5em` = `2em`.